# Why does my app descriptor file keep changing?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, publish, descriptor

I'm using flash cs6 and i have ticked the box manually manage permissions and manifest additions in the application descriptor file, I have made some changes in the descriptor file and when I publish my app it changes back, why does this happen? Im using air 4.0.0.1390 for android.

Comment: Are you clicking on permissions tab every time you publish?

Comment: @Rajneesh Gaikwad no this happends when i just click file -> publish from flash cs6, then over in flash develop it says this file has been modified externally do you want to refresh ?